# How to parse JSON ( Array Data) in c#

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c

I am sending JSON data to asp.net but i cannot read what it is in it.What i want to is I want to read JSON Array values as  Key Pair data

(void)checkWithServer:(NSDictionary*)data {
    // Create the POST request payload.

```
NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"user/login",@"routeFunc",data, @"data",
                     nil];
NSError *error;
 NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];

NSString *serverURL = baseURLDefault;

// Create the POST request to the server.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postdata length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postdata];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSLog(@"%@",[[request URL]absoluteString]);
[conn start];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                   queue: queue
                       completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (error || !data) {
                               NSLog(@"sonuc %@ %@",error,data);
                           } else {
                               NSError *parseError = nil;
                               NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
                               NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                               NSDictionary *dic = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
                               NSLog(@"%@ %@",dic,dictionary);
                               if (!dictionary) {
                                   NSLog(@"%s: JSONObjectWithData error: %@; data = %@", __FUNCTION__, parseError, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                   return;
                               }
                           }
                       }
 ];
}
```

I tried this to read but not worked

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
   dict.Add(key,Request.QueryString[key]);
}
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write(json);
```

Comment: Hi @user3236289, you post your data in the body of the request, you can't read by the Request.QueryString. Post entirely your method backend C# code please.

Comment: var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
   dict.Add(key,Request.QueryString[key]);
}
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write(json);

Comment: this also not working 
JObject data = JObject.Parse(Request.QueryString["data"]);